# Using session.set_expiry() in custom AuthenticationForm in Django.

Tags: django, session, authentication

I am trying to set remember me in login and use LoginView as view. Is it possible to set session.set_expiry(0) in the custom AuthenticationForm?

```
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField();
    password = forms.CharField(),
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
                             label='Remember me')

    def clean_remember_me(self):
      if not self.cleaned_data['remember_me']:
         set expiry immediately <-- here
```

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE might be usable but can I use session.get_expiry(0) in this case?

How can I do without writing a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this as [request is passed to the form from view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L85):

```
def clean_remember_me(self):
  if not self.cleaned_data['remember_me']:
     self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
  ...
```